# Some algebraic step I'm missing? Exponentiation and log related.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$100(1-\frac{12 \cdot 0.85^{a+1}}{12 \cdot 0.85^a})$

As seen [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100%281-%28%2812*0.85%5E%28a%2b1%29%29/%28%2812*0.85%5Ea%29%29%29%29)(Or pic below), this evaluates to 15.

[image]

There is one step I am worried is wrong, can I just rewrite the exponentiations over like this?

$100(1-\frac{12 \cdot (a+1) \cdot \log 0.85}{12 \cdot a \cdot \log 0.85})$

Because in the end I end up with the following
$\frac{100}{a}$
Instead of 15.

Comment: The proposed rewriting is not correct.  You **could** rewrite, for example, $0.85^{a+1}$ as $10^{(a+1)\log(0.85)}$ if by $\log$ you mean logarithm to base $10$, or replace $10$ by $e$ if by $\log$ you mean the natural logarithm. The rewriting would not be helpful, however. You can simplify directly, $u^{a+1}/u^a=u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you took the logarithm of one piece of the expression, which will not preserve anything about it (*and note, even if you took the logarithm of the entire expression*, you would then be looking to prove it was equal to $\log(15)$, not $15$). For example, if we had the expression
$$1-\frac{10^5}{10^2}$$
(which is equal to $1-1000=-999$)
it's incorrect to claim it's equal to 
$$1-\frac{5\log(10)}{2\log(10)}=1-\frac{5}{2}=-\frac{3}{2}$$
However, in your problem, what you can do is note that
$$0.85^{a+1}=0.85\times 0.85^a$$
and divide.

Comment: What algebraic rules is that last bit based on? Neat stuff, would love to read more about it.

Comment: It is one of the [basic properties of exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties).

Comment: That way of using this rule never occurred to me, thanks.